# Auto scroll to particular row in Android Tablelayout

Tags: android, scroll, tablelayout

I have android Table Layout as follows:

MonthName  Date    Day    Event

January    1-Jan   Mon    Eric Birthday Party 
January    15-Jan  Tue    Doctor Appointment
February   1-Feb   Mon    Doctor Appointment
March      1-Mar   Mon    Steve Birthday Party
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   |
November   15-Nov   Mon    Joy Birthday Party
December   25-Dec   Mon    Christmas

Entire data is displayed from database dynamically.
I want to ask that how to auto scroll directly to current month i.e November in above tablelayout.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 40;
View child = mytablelayout.getChildAt(index);
myscrollview.scrollTo(0, child.getTop());
```

Basically you just need to get the position of the view and tell the scrollview to scroll to it. This requires you to have a reference to the item you want to scroll to but you can also get that dynamically.